# Why is there no Unix command for gethostbyname?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system

I know there is [host](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_%28Unix%29) and [dig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dig_%28Command%29) and all those... but they are DNS tools and they don't query the local resolver library.

`/etc/hosts` can change what the local resolver returns. The local resolver does caching too. `/etc/nsswitch.conf` can completely remove DNS from the resolution path...

So it seems wierd that there is no command for checking what the local resolver library has.

I normally do something like this:

```
export VAR='"nics-acer"'; python -c "import socket; print(socket.gethostbyname($VAR));"
```

and when I wrote my Python version of [resolvconf](https://github.com/nicferrier/resolvconfpy), I added a switch to test the resolver, but shouldn't there be a reason for there not being a standard tool?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is such command: `getent`.

Try following: `getent hosts google.com`, `getent hosts 8.8.8.8` - it will query using system resolver (see also `/etc/nsswitch.conf` to check what is actually being queries and in what order).